# problems with saving information to Data in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I used containers to build layouts which worked well everywhere, and here on the statistics where there is a pie chart, everything is floated.

If it is not the reason that it increases over time, and if so how to fix it ?

Here is an XML code. Please help or give any useful information on how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/statisricfon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_for_stat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numpoint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="370dp"
            android:text="120" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numtry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="235dp"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numanswear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:text="18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numtruavt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="620dp"
            android:text="23" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numtopscore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="425dp"
            android:text="15" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart

            android:id="@+id/piecha"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

            ></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot :**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't  understand what is your problem? you want to show a pie chart

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few red flags in the way you decided to implement this layout.

First a bit context, there are endless variations of Android devices out there, with different physical screen sizes, [resolutions](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes), and subsequently [dpis](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

---

Ideally, you would move away from `RelativeLayout` and use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) instead. And if the `PieChart` width and height can change over time so the view itself has to manage that in its `onMeasure` method regardless.

---

It would also make sense to get rid of `@drawable/statisricfon` and replace it with a few [Android XML drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape) and vector images. This will ensure that the design would scale well on different screen configurations including portrait, landscape, and [multi-window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) modes.

You can use one drawable for the gradient:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="integer"
        android:centerColor="integer"
        android:endColor="color"
        android:startColor="color"
        android:gradientRadius="integer"
        android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"] />
</shape>
```

And for the question marks, you can use a repeated pattern instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:src="@drawable/pattern" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

And lastly, custom views for the `TextView`s with that white box background and title.